# Why won't this GLSL Vertex Shader compile?

Tags: opengl, glsl, vertex-shader

I'm writing my own shader with OpenGL, and I am stumped why this shader won't compile. Could anyone else have a look at it?

What I'm passing in as a vertex is 2 floats (separated as bytes) in this format:

```
Float 1:

Byte 1: Position X
Byte 2: Position Y
Byte 3: Position Z
Byte 4: Texture Coordinate X


Float 2:

Byte 1: Color R
Byte 2: Color G 
Byte 3: Color B
Byte 4: Texture Coordinate Y
```

And this is my shader:

```
in vec2 Data;
varying vec3 Color;
varying vec2 TextureCoords;

uniform mat4 projection_mat;
uniform mat4 view_mat;
uniform mat4 world_mat;

void main() 
{
    vec4 dataPosition = UnpackValues(Data.x);
    vec4 dataColor = UnpackValues(Data.y);

    vec4 position = dataPosition * vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    Color = dataColor.xyz;

    TextureCoords = vec2(dataPosition.w, dataColor.w)

    gl_Position = projection_mat * view_mat * world_mat * position;
}

vec4 UnpackValues(float value)
{
    return vec4(value % 255, (value >> 8) % 255, (value >> 16) % 255, value >> 24);
}
```

If you need any more information, I'd be happy to comply.

Comment: Please copy paste the error message.

Comment: How do I receive an error message? I get one when I call glGetProgramInfoLog, but that is just "Vertex shader(s) were not successfully compiled before glLinkProgram() was called.  Link failed."

Comment: @Azzi777: There is glGetShaderInfoLog, which works when glCompileShader fails. You should _always_ check the compile status of shader objects and program objects.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to declare `UnpackValues` *before* you call it. GLSL is like C and C++; names must have a declaration before they can be used.

---

BTW: What you're trying to do *will not work*. Floats are floats; unless you're working with GLSL 4.00 (and since you continue to use old terms like "varying", I'm guessing not), you cannot extract bits out of a float. Indeed, the right-shift operator is only defined for integers; attempting to use it on floats will fail with a compiler error.

GLSL is not C or C++ (ironically).

If you want to pack your data, use OpenGL to pack it for you. Send two vec4 attributes that contain normalized unsigned bytes:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(X, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, GL_TRUE, 8, *);
glVertexAttribPointer(Y, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, GL_TRUE, 8, * + 4);
```

Your vertex shader would take two `vec4` values as inputs. Since you are not using glVertexAttrib**I**Pointer, OpenGL knows that you're passing values that are to be interpreted as floats.

Comment: Thank you for your help, the shader compiles now. I'm having some problems with glGetVertexAttribute, though. Can you explain in which order I should call, glGenBuffer, glBindBuffer (should I call glSetData?), and what else I need to call to actually transfer the vertex data to the shader? Thanks in advance

Comment: @Azzi777: Many of the functions you cited (`glGetVertexAttribute`, `glSetData`) don't exist. It seems like your original question has been answered. If you have a question about how to send vertex data, you should ask that as a new question.